# How to specify another properties file other than hibernate.properties

Tags: hibernate

I have a "hibernate.properties" for product, and I want one more for testing.

So I created a "hibernate.test.properties" in the classpath, but I don't know how to let hibernate use it. It always used the "hibernate.properties" one.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this HibernateUtil class. It loads XML and properties files without standar name. Hope it be useful.

```
public class HibernateUtil2 {
  private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

  private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        URL r1 = HibernateUtil2.class.getResource("/hibernate2.cfg.xml");
        Configuration c = new Configuration().configure(r1);

        try {
            InputStream is = HibernateUtil2.class.getResourceAsStream("/hibernate2.properties");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(is);
            c.addProperties(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Error al leer las propiedades", e);
        }

        return c.buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
        LOG.error("Error al construir SessionFactory", ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}